# Selecting the last 3 characters of a string SQL

Tags: sql, string, count, sql-server-2016

can someone help me with some SQL I am struggling with.

I need to select the final 3 characters of a field containing a file name (so I can grab the extension of said files).   Ideally, I'd like a count of these values.

Selecting the first 3 characters of a string is simple enough, but I don't know how to select the final 3 - the filenames are all differing lengths.

Thank you.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: you mean something like `RIGHT(YourString,3)`?

Comment: No I think he means, add tags like how you added "sql", "string" and  "count"

Comment: An example of the contents of the field would be :-  Images/Batch_02/000131343_01.pdf
Images/Batch_02/000131365_01.pdf
kestrel\batch30\000177170_01.zip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two common ways are:

```
select right(filename, 3)
select substr(filename, -3)
```

However, I would caution you that not all filenames have 3 characters.  I would suggest that you ask another question, with more information and examples of the filenames you are using.

Answer (score 1):

In case the file extension isn't only 3 characters... and you don't have any periods anywhere else.

```
declare @somefile varchar(64) = '/server/folder/sub_folder/file.extension'

select
    substring(@somefile,charindex('.',@somefile) + 1,99)
```

Or if you do have periods in the file path which is possible but not wise.

```
declare @somefile varchar(64) = '/ser.ver/fo.lder/sub.folder/file.extension'

select
    right(@someFile,charindex('.',reverse(@somefile)) - 1)
```